# template for thesis

Tags: templates, thesis

I have decided to write my thesis with LaTex. There is a specific format for the first three pages of the report which are prescribed by the University. Since I am new to LaTex, I am finding it difficult to create them.

Can anyone help me out with this? Would be really helpful.Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports. You should also read [an introduction](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/).  You can also have a look at [Customizing titlepage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage).

Comment: You should complain to the university. I have never seen something as ugly as this stuff.

Comment: Why don't you just fill out the blanks in Word and print it? I don't see a need to recreate this in any way.

Comment: Something you need: the font (that's maybe Helvetica, I think), the margin setting by `geometry` package, something to add a line from the left edge of the page to the right edge, and maybe some tables...

Comment: @JouleV I doubt the dotted lines are needed in print if the document is filled out electronically. People need it when they fill out the paper with a pen.

Comment: @Johannes_B I would say the same thing if we were in the past. But now I don't think that students need to write thesis by hand, especially in Germany. (I can see that the OP is a student in Darmstadt).

Comment: I find it hard to believe that no one at your university has ever written their thesis in tex before (at a university of Applied Sciences, in a faculty of electronics and information technology!). Ask around, particularly from your thesis advisor, and your fellow students.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to convert these (extremely ugly) pages to LaTeX I would suggest the following:

1. Use Word to fill them out (or whatever other tool they are provided for)
2. Export as PDF (or use a print-to-pdf driver if the tool does not support exporting as PDF)
3. Use the [`pdfpages`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) package to include those pages at the beginning of your LaTeX document
4. Build with [`pdflatex`](https://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex/) or [`lualatex`](http://www.luatex.org/)

Example:

```
% select paper type to match your pdf, I am assuming A4 as h_da is in Germany
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
% include the pdfpages package
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
    % use \includepdf at the beginning of your document.
    % pages=- causes all pages to be included.
    % the filename must not contain spaces.
    \includepdf[pages=-]{yourExport.pdf}
\end{document}
```